# How do I arrange data in ascending datetime and text in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have below-mentioned dataframe in R:

```
ID      Datetime                  Name
P-1     2020-04-03 24:14:18       John
P-2     2020-04-01 15:24:20       Alex
P-3     2020-04-02 18:43:09       Carl
```

I want to sort the above data frame in ascending order by `Datetime` and `Name`.

Required Dataframe -

```
ID      Datetime                  Name
P-2     2020-04-01 15:24:20       Alex
P-3     2020-04-02 18:43:09       Carl
P-1     2020-04-03 24:14:18       John
```

Comment: try `arrange` from `dplyr`

Comment: `df %>% mutate(Datetime = ymd_hms(Datetime)) %>% arrange(Datetime)` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: or `df %>% arrange(as.POSIXct(Datetime), Name)`